src.toArrayLike is not a function
I am trying to do a dapp on Solona with Next.js and Ancor.
I am getting that error 
Here is my program setup
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

export const program = new Program<AnchorMarketplace>(IDL, program_pk, {
  connection,
});

That is how I use program
const listTx = program.methods
    .list(0.005)
    .accounts({
      maker: signer,
      marketplace: marketplacePda.toBase58(),
      makerMint: CPT_address,
      collectionMint: signer,
      vault: vault.toBase58(),
      metadata: metadata.toBase58(),
      metadataProgram: metadataProgramAddress,
      makerAta: makerATA.toBase58(),
      listing: listingPda.toBase58(),
      associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBase58(),
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId.toBase58(),
    })
    .transaction();


The parameter that you are passing, which is 0.005, must be of BigNumber type.
Import BN class from anchor and put the number inside it, that will fix your problem.
It should look like:
import { BN } from `@coral-xyz/anchor`;

const listTx = program.methods
    .list(new BN(0.005))
    .accounts({
      maker: signer,
      marketplace: marketplacePda.toBase58(),
      makerMint: CPT_address,
      collectionMint: signer,
      vault: vault.toBase58(),
      metadata: metadata.toBase58(),
      metadataProgram: metadataProgramAddress,
      makerAta: makerATA.toBase58(),
      listing: listingPda.toBase58(),
      associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBase58(),
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId.toBase58(),
    })
    .transaction();


In my case It had nothing to do with the BN function, I got the same error because the parameters I was passing to the program.methods function had the wrong order.
